# computer won't boot, number in bottom right

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, multi-boot

My system setup was like this:
1 SSD with windows 7 installed and a 
second HD with ubuntu installed

At startup i could choose which OS to boot with grub (i assume)

but then i got the luminous idea to format the HD that ubuntu was on and assign that as a mount point on my SSD as c:\extra, don't ask, i could smack myself in the head for this.

Everything was fine, until i booted my PC this morning and i just stops after a few seconds with an idle prompt in the topleft and the number 92 in the bottom right, anything i try fails ... it even doesn't display the splash screen to enter bios!?

What could be causing this? My guess is that grub or another bootmanager is barfed. How can i investigate and solve this problem?

Comment: When you formatted your SSD your got rid of your bootsector.  I should point out, if you see something happen, then you already way past loading your system's bios,

Comment: i haven't formatted the SSD, i formatted the second HD. And the thing is ... the black screen i'm staring at right now has "Entering setup..." at the bottom left but it just doesn't continue from there on. thus, i can hit F8 to try to enter bios config but it doesn't happen

Comment: disconnect your hd and try booting , and if you were using grub menu to startup you have a lot of repairing to do

Comment: disconnecting didn't help, can you point me in the direction where to start looking what needs repairing? If i could get it into a state that i could actually do something i'd be happy :)

Comment: Are you able to boot on a linux live CD ?
And for how long did it work until it broke ?